# Is this database in 1NF, 2NF and 3NF?

Tags: normalization

I'm doing a software development course and I have to normalise my tables as part of it. Can anyone double check that my data is normalised correctly?

The database is for a gym. It has these tables currently:

```
Member - Storing member details

Membership - Storing memberships, these are attached to each Member

MembershipType - Storing the type of membership so that I don't
                 waste space storing it for each membership

Booking - Storing bookings made by a member

Class - Storing the details of each of the classes offered by the gym

Room - For storing the name of the room the class is in so that if 
       the name of the room changes it only needs updating once
```

Here's my initial ER Diagram:

```
--------- 1     1 --------
| Class |---------| Room |
---------         --------
1   |
    |
M   |
--------- M     1 -------- 1     M ------------ 1     1 ---------------- 
|Booking|---------|Member|---------|Membership|---------|MembershipType|
---------         --------         ------------         ----------------
                                   1     |
                                         |
                                   M     |
                                   ------------
                                   |  Payment |
                                   ------------
```

> Here's my 1NF data:

Member(**MemberID**, Title, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, PostCode, PhoneNumber, Email, Gender)

Membership(**MembershipID**, **MemberID***, StartDate, EndDate, AgreedPrice, **MembershipTypeID***, Duration, Price, PaymentSchedule)

Booking(**BookingID**, **MemberID***, ClassID, RoomName, ClassName, MaxSize, ClassDate, ClassTime, Duration)

Payment(**PaymentID**, **MembershipID**, PaymentAmount, DateReceived, PaymentMethod)

> Here's my 2NF data:

Member(**MemberID**, Title, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, PostCode, PhoneNumber, Email, Gender)

Membership(**MembershipID**, **MemberID***, StartDate, EndDate, AgreedPrice, **MembershipTypeID***, Duration, Price, PaymentSchedule)

Booking(**BookingID**, **MemberID***)

Class(**ClassID**, RoomName, ClassName, MaxSize, ClassDate, ClassTime, Duration)

Payment(**PaymentID**, **MembershipID**, PaymentAmount, DateReceived, PaymentMethod)

> Here's my 3NF data:

Member(**MemberID**, Title, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, PostCode, PhoneNumber, Email, Gender)

Membership(**MembershipID**, **MemberID***, **MembershipTypeID*** StartDate, EndDate, AgreedPrice)

MembershipType(**MembershipTypeID**, Duration, Price, PaymentSchedule)

Booking(**BookingID**, **MemberID***)

Class(**ClassID**, **RoomID***, ClassName, MaxSize, ClassDate, ClassTime, Duration)

Room(**RoomID**, RoomName)

Payment(**PaymentID**, **MembershipID**, PaymentAmount, DateReceived, PaymentMethod)

---

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.